# How to wait Angular 5 Observable?

Tags: angular5

Hi) I am using Angular 5 and I have Configuration service.

```
...
@Injectable()
export class Configuration {
  public cultures = Array<Culture>();
  constructor(
    private cultureService: CultureService,
    private translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    this.cultureService.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.cultures = data.map(function(s) {
          return new Culture(s.id, s.code, s.name);
        });
        console.log(this.cultures);
      },
      error => console.log('& app.config ' + error + ' &'),
      () => {}
    );   
  }
}
```

And I have DashboardComponent. In DashboardComponent, cultures array is called from Configuration service. But when cultures array is called, Configuration service returns empty cultures array. In the constructor of Configuration service cultureService.getAll() Observable method is working, but it is being late. Question: how to wait observable method until it completes?

```
...

@Component({
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  langs = [];
  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private configuration: Configuration
  ) {        
      console.log(configuration.cultures);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  changeLang(language: Culture): void {
    this.translate.use(language.code);
    localStorage.setItem('lang', language.code);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. Observables are only supposed to fire if someone does a `next()` to it. Only then can you get something out of the `subscribe()`. 
I replicated your code and it works as intended. This is my variation on it:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
  result: any;

  constructor(private $culture: CultureService) {
    this.$culture.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.result = data.map(x => {
        return new Culture(x);
      });
      console.log(this.result);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

My getAll() function is this one:

```
  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next([2, 3, 4]);
      }, 3000)
    });
  }
```

As you can see, I simulated a delayed `next()` to the Observable. As expected, the `console.log()` would only happen *when* the `next()` happens.

**[Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-wait-observable)**

If this doesn't answer your question, replicate your issue there and I'll try to help anyway I can.

Comment: Altus) what happens if duration lasts more than 3s ?

Comment: The same. The `console.log()`s in the `subscribe()` would only happen after N seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Try this 
        In Configuration service ----
        @Injectable()
        export class Configuration {
          public cultures = new BehaviorSubject(Array<Culture>());
          constructor(
            private cultureService: CultureService,
            private translate: TranslateService
          ) {
            this.cultureService.getAll().subscribe(
              data => {
                let res = data.map(function(s) {
                  return new Culture(s.id, s.code, s.name);
                });
                this.cultures.next(res);
              },
              error => console.log('& app.config ' + error + ' &'),
              () => {}
            );   
          }
        }

    In DashboardComponent -----
    @Component({
      templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
    })
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
      langs = [];
      constructor(
        private translate: TranslateService,
        private configuration: Configuration
      ) {
          configuration.cultures.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log("Subscription got", value);
          });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      changeLang(language: Culture): void {
        this.translate.use(language.code);
        localStorage.setItem('lang', language.code);
      }
    }
```